# Problems using foreach parallelization

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to compare parallelization options. Specifically, I'm comparing the standard `SNOW` and `mulitcore` implementations to those using `doSNOW` or `doMC` and `foreach`. As a sample problem, I'm illustrating the central limit theorem by computing the means of samples drawn from a standard normal distribution many times. Here's the standard code:

```
CltSim <- function(nSims=1000, size=100, mu=0, sigma=1){
  sapply(1:nSims, function(x){
    mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  })
}
```

Here's the `SNOW` implementation:

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(2)

ParCltSim <- function(cluster, nSims=1000, size=100, mu=0, sigma=1){
  parSapply(cluster, 1:nSims, function(x){
    mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  })
}
```

Next, the `doSNOW` method:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

FECltSim <- function(nSims=1000, size=100, mu=0, sigma=1) {
  x <- numeric(nSims)
  foreach(i=1:nSims, .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
    x[i] <- mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
> system.time(CltSim(nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.476   0.008   0.484 
> system.time(ParCltSim(cluster=cl, nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.028   0.004   0.375 
> system.time(FECltSim(nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.865   0.408  11.309
```

The `SNOW` implementation shaves off about 23% of computing time relative to an unparallelized run (time savings get bigger as the number of simulations increase, as we would expect). The `foreach` attempt actually **increases** run time by a factor of 20. Additionally, if I change `%dopar%` to `%do%` and check the unparallelized version of the loop, it takes over 7 seconds.

Additionally, we can consider the `multicore` package. The simulation written for `multicore` is

```
library(multicore)
MCCltSim <- function(nSims=1000, size=100, mu=0, sigma=1){
  unlist(mclapply(1:nSims, function(x){
    mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  }))
}
```

We get an even better speed improvement than `SNOW`:

```
> system.time(MCCltSim(nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.924   0.032   0.307
```

Starting a new R session, we can attempt the `foreach` implementation using `doMC` instead of `doSNOW`, calling

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
```

then running `FECltSim()` as above, still finding

```
> system.time(FECltSim(nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.800   0.024   6.887
```

This is "only" a 14-fold increase over the non-parallelized runtime.

Conclusion: My `foreach` code is not running efficiently under either `doSNOW` or `doMC`. Any idea why?

Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, you could write your foreach code a bit more concise :

```
FECltSim <- function(nSims=1000, size=100, mu=0, sigma=1) {
  foreach(i=1:nSims, .combine=c) %dopar% {
    mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  }
}
```

This gives you a vector, no need to explicitly make it within the loop. Also no need to use cbind, as your result is every time just a single number. So `.combine=c` will do

The thing with foreach is that it creates quite a lot of overhead to communicate between the cores and get the results of the different cores fit together. A quick look at the profile shows this pretty clearly :

```
$by.self
                         self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
$                             5.46    41.30       5.46     41.30
$<-                           0.76     5.75       0.76      5.75
.Call                         0.76     5.75       0.76      5.75
...
```

More than 40% of the time it is busy selecting things. It also uses a lot of other functions for the whole operation. Actually, `foreach` is only advisable if you have relatively few rounds through very time consuming functions.

The other two solutions are built on a different technology, and do far less in R. On a sidenode, `snow` is actually initially developed to work on clusters more than on single workstations, like `multicore` is.

Comment: Thanks again, Jons. I actually haven't used Rprof before, would you be able to explain how to interpret this output or point me to a resource that could? I looked at R's native help files for `summaryRprof` and it wasn't that helpful.

Comment: @Charlie : self.time is the time that is spent in the function itself. self.pct is then the percentage of the total time that is spent in the function itself. total.time is the time spent in that function or any other function it calls. eg : `f1 <- function(x){f2(x)}`, then self.time is the time in `f1()` alone, and total.time is the time in `f1()` and `f2()`-if called from f1() !. total.pct is again the percentage of the total time. It's a bit confusing in the beginning, but very powerful for optimization.

Comment: Thanks. How about `$`, `$<-`, `.Call`, and I'm guessing others? Is there a document that explains what each of these represents?

Comment: I checked the help files (`summaryRprof` and `Rprof`), but they didn't discuss the interpretation.

Comment: @Charlie : I meant the help files of .Call, '$' and so on.

Answer (score 5):

To follow on something Joris said, `foreach()` is best when the number of jobs does not hugely exceed the number of processors you will be using.  Or more generally, when each job takes a significant amount of time on its own (seconds or minutes, say).  There is a lot of overhead in creating the threads, so you really don't want to use it for lots of small jobs.  If you were doing 10 million sims rather than 10 thousand, and you structured your code like this:

```
nSims = 1e7
nBatch = 1e6
foreach(i=1:(nSims/nBatch), .combine=c) %dopar% {
  replicate(nBatch, mean(rnorm(n=size, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
}
```

I bet you would find that foreach was doing pretty well.

Also note the use of `replicate()` for this kind of application rather than sapply.  Actually, the `foreach` package has a similar convenience function, `times()`, which could be applied in this case.  Of course, if your code is not doing a simple simulations with identical parameters every time, you will need `sapply()` and `foreach()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of breaking the process into batches; I'll bet that'll save a good bit of communication time. I had seen `replicate` before, but not `times`.