# MPI parallelization using SNOW is slow

Tags: r, parallel-processing

My [foray into parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007458/problems-using-foreach-parallelization) continues. I initially had difficulty installing `Rmpi`, but I got that going (I needed to `sudo apt-get` it). I should say that I'm running a machine with Ubuntu 10.10.

I ran the same simulation as my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007458/problems-using-foreach-parallelization). Recall the system times for the unclustered and `SNOW` SOCK cluster respectively:

```
> system.time(CltSim(nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.476   0.008   0.484 
> system.time(ParCltSim(cluster=cl, nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.028   0.004   0.375
```

Now, using an MPI cluster, I get a speed **slowdown** relative to not clustering:

```
> stopCluster(cl)
> cl <- getMPIcluster()
> system.time(ParCltSim(cluster=cl, nSims=10000, size=100))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.088   0.196   0.604
```

Not sure whether this is useful, but here's info on the cluster created:

```
> cl
[[1]]
$rank
[1] 1

$RECVTAG
[1] 33

$SENDTAG
[1] 22

$comm
[1] 1

attr(,"class")
[1] "MPInode"

[[2]]
$rank
[1] 2

$RECVTAG
[1] 33

$SENDTAG
[1] 22

$comm
[1] 1

attr(,"class")
[1] "MPInode"

attr(,"class")
[1] "spawnedMPIcluster" "MPIcluster"        "cluster"
```

Any idea about what could be going on here? Thanks for your assistance as I try out these parallelization options.

Cordially,
Charlie

Comment: I suspect there's enough overhead which is causing your runs to slow down. I use snowfall (works out of the box on unix and windows) and I get nice speed ups, but my tasks are rather time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit the same as with your other question : the communication between the nodes in the cluster is taking up more time than the actual function.

This can be illustrated by changing your functions :

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(2)

SnowSim <- function(cluster, nSims=10,n){
  parSapply(cluster, 1:nSims, function(x){
    Sys.sleep(n)
    x
  })
}



library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

ForSim <- function(nSims=10,n) {
  foreach(i=1:nSims, .combine=c) %dopar% {
      Sys.sleep(n)
      i
  }
}
```

This way we can simulate a long-calculating and a short-calculating function in different numbers of simulations. Let's take two cases, one where you have 1 sec calculation and 10 loops, and one with 1ms calculation and 10000 loops. Both should last 10sec :

```
> system.time(SnowSim(cl,10,1))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       5 

> system.time(ForSim(10,1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    5.03 

> system.time(SnowSim(cl,10000,0.001))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    9.78 

> system.time(ForSim(10000,0.001))
   user  system elapsed 
  10.04    0.00   19.81
```

Basically what you see, is that for long-calculating functions and low simulations, the parallelized versions cleanly cut the calculation time in half as expected.

Now the simulations you do are of the second case. There you see that the `snow` solution doesn't really make a difference any more, and that the `foreach` solution even needs twice as much. This is simply due to the overhead of communication to and between nodes, and handling of the data that gets returned. The overhead of `foreach` is a lot bigger than with `snow`, as shown in my answer to your previous question.

I didn't fire up my Ubuntu to try with an MPI cluster, but it's basically the same story. There are subtle differences between the different types of clusters according to time needed for communication, partly due to differences between the underlying packages.

Comment: Jons, Thanks so much for this clear and clever illustration! I'll try your idea using MPI to check it out. I had assumed that each cluster would do its own thing and only join the results at the end, so I was expecting an essentially fixed cost of communicating that was independent of the number of simulations, but the cost of communicating seems to scale linearly with the number of simulations. This leads me to believe that the clusters communicate after each run---is that right? Do you know of a good rule-of-thumb for when running in parallel saves you time and when it can cost you? Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie : I have no rule-of-thumb, but I only use parallelization if my inner functions take pretty long. The communication is necessary, as the computer has to know which core is free to send the next command to, and has to know which result comes from which loop instance to keep the results in good order.