# Is there an efficient way to parallelize mapply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have many rows and on every row I compute the uniroot of a non-linear function. I have a quad-core Ubuntu machine which hasn't stopped running my code for two days now. Not surprisingly, I'm looking for ways to speed things up ;-)

After some research, I noticed that only one core is currently used and parallelization is the thing to do. Digging deeper, I came to the conclusion (maybe incorrectly?) that the package `foreach` isn't really meant for my problem because too much overhead is produced (see, for example, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012804/mpi-parallelization-using-snow-is-slow)). A good alternative seems to be `multicore` for Unix machines. In particular, the `pvec` function seems to be the most efficient one after I checked the help page.

However, if I understand it correctly, this function only takes **one** vector and splits it up accordingly. I need a function that can be parallized, but takes **multiple** vectors (or a `data.frame` instead), just like the `mapply` function does. Is there anything out there that I missed?

Here is a small example of what I want to do: (Note that I include a `plyr` example here because it can be an alternative to the base `mapply` function and it has a parallelize option. However, it is slower in my implementation and internally, it calls `foreach` to parallelize, so I think it won't help. Is that correct?)

```
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(P   = rnorm(n, mean=100, sd=10),
                 B0  = rnorm(n, mean=40,  sd=5),
                 CF1 = rnorm(n, mean=30,  sd=10),
                 CF2 = rnorm(n, mean=30,  sd=5),
                 CF3 = rnorm(n, mean=90,  sd=8))

get_uniroot <- function(P, B0, CF1, CF2, CF3) {

  uniroot(function(x) {-P + B0 + CF1/x + CF2/x^2 + CF3/x^3}, 
          lower = 1,
          upper = 10,
          tol   = 0.00001)$root

}

system.time(x1 <- mapply(get_uniroot, df$P, df$B0, df$CF1, df$CF2, df$CF3))
   #user  system elapsed 
   #0.91    0.00    0.90 
system.time(x2 <- mdply(df, get_uniroot))
   #user  system elapsed 
   #5.85    0.00    5.85
system.time(x3 <- foreach(P=df$P, B0=df$B0, CF1=df$CF1, CF2=df$CF2, CF3=df$CF3, .combine = "c") %do% {
    get_uniroot(P, B0, CF1, CF2, CF3)})
   #user  system elapsed 
  # 10.30    0.00   10.36
all.equal(x1, x2$V1) #TRUE
all.equal(x1, x3)    #TRUE
```

Also, I tried to implement Ryan Thompson's function chunkapply from the SO link above (only got rid of `doMC` part, because I couldn't install it. His example works, though, even after adjusting his function.),
but didn't get it to work. However, since it uses `foreach`, I thought the same arguments mentioned above apply, so I didn't try it too long.

```
#chunkapply(get_uniroot, list(P=df$P, B0=df$B0, CF1=df$CF1, CF2=df$CF2, CF3=df$CF3))
#Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid function value in 'zeroin'"
```

PS: I know that I could just increase `tol` to reduce the number of steps that are necessary to find a uniroot. However, I already set `tol` as big as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use the `parallel` package that's built into R 2.14 and work with matrices. You could then simply use `mclapply` like this:

```
dfm <- as.matrix(df)
result <- mclapply(seq_len(nrow(dfm)),
          function(x) do.call(get_uniroot,as.list(dfm[x,])),
          mc.cores=4L
          )
unlist(result)
```

This is basically doing the same mapply does, but in a parallel way.

**But...**

Mind you that parallelization always counts for some overhead as well. As I explained in the question you link to, going parallel only pays off if your inner function calculates significantly longer than the overhead involved. In your case, your uniroot function works pretty fast. You might then consider to cut your data frame in bigger chunks, and combine both mapply and mclapply. A possible way to do this is:

```
ncores <- 4
id <- floor(
        quantile(0:nrow(df),
                 1-(0:ncores)/ncores
        )
      )
idm <- embed(id,2)

mapply_uniroot <- function(id){
  tmp <- df[(id[1]+1):id[2],]
  mapply(get_uniroot, tmp$P, tmp$B0, tmp$CF1, tmp$CF2, tmp$CF3)
}
result <-mclapply(nrow(idm):1,
                  function(x) mapply_uniroot(idm[x,]),
                  mc.cores=ncores)
final <- unlist(result)
```

This might need some tweaking, but it essentially breaks your df in exactly as many bits as there are cores, and run the mapply on every core. To show this works :

```
> x1 <- mapply(get_uniroot, df$P, df$B0, df$CF1, df$CF2, df$CF3)
> all.equal(final,x1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and the example. This is what I was looking for. Also, I wasn't aware that `parallel` was available from R2.14.0 on, that's good to know as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Parallel still has to be loaded before you can use it of course, but it comes with the standard installation.

Answer (score 4):

it's an old topic but fyi you now have `parallel::mcmapply` doc is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html). don't forget to set `mc.cores` in the options. I usually use `mc.cores=parallel::detectCores()-1` to let one cpu free for OS operations.

`x4 <- mcmapply(get_uniroot, df$P, df$B0, df$CF1, df$CF2, df$CF3,mc.cores=parallel::detectCores()-1)`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly a best practices suggestion, but considerable speed-up can be had by identifying the root for all parameters in a 'vectorized' fashion. For instance,

```
bisect <-
    function(f, interval, ..., lower=min(interval), upper=max(interval),
             f.lower=f(lower, ...), f.upper=f(upper, ...), maxiter=20)
{
    nrow <- length(f.lower)
    bounds <- matrix(c(lower, upper), nrow, 2, byrow=TRUE)
    for (i in seq_len(maxiter)) {
        ## move lower or upper bound to mid-point, preserving opposite signs
        mid <- rowSums(bounds) / 2
        updt <- ifelse(f(mid, ...) > 0, 0L, nrow) + seq_len(nrow)
        bounds[updt] <- mid
    }
    rowSums(bounds) / 2
}
```

and then

```
> system.time(x2 <- with(df, {
+     f <- function(x, PB0, CF1, CF2, CF3)
+         PB0 + CF1/x + CF2/x^2 + CF3/x^3
+     bisect(f, c(1, 10), PB0, CF1, CF2, CF3)
+ }))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.180   0.000   0.181 
> range(x1 - x2)
[1] -6.282406e-06  6.658593e-06
```

versus about 1.3s for application of uniroot separately to each. This also combined P and B0 into a single value ahead of time, since that is how they enter the equation.

The bounds on the final value are `+/- diff(interval) * (.5 ^ maxiter)` or so. A fancier implementation would replace bisection with linear or quadratic interpolation (as in the reference cited in `?uniroot`), but then uniform efficient convergence (and in all cases error handling) would be more tricky to arrange.

Comment: Wow, that's quite an out-of-the-box solution, and a great one! Since it doesn't answer the question to parallelize mapply, I accepted Joris' answer. But I will definitely try to implement yours in combination with what Joris proposed. The only shortcoming I see with your approach is that you can't be sure anymore what tolerance every solution has because you set the number of steps over all rows, not the tolerance. So I guess I have to open up my mathbooks again and check if I can make any statements such as: given a polynomial with N degrees and 20 iterations, the tolerance is maximum x.

Comment: I just asked myself for quite some time why Martin resets the `i` loop-variable all the time in the loop and how that even works since `i <- ifelse(f(mid, ...) > 0, 0L, nrow) + seq_len(nrow)` returns a vector, not a number. Then I figured out that the inner `i` and the outer one have nothing in common except their name. I'm quite surprised that this works, so this is just a hint for others that are not so familiar with the inner workings of R and are struggling with that one.

Comment: I'm surprised that double use of `i` worked, too! I changed the code.