# Best apply function for a large data set which takes multiple arguments

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I got a big data set.

When I used mapply, I got this time for running the code for one instance(I have 400 thousand instances)

`user  system elapsed 
 0.49    0.05    0.53`
function takes 2 arguments as input.

Got the idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078211/use-multiple-columns-as-variables-with-sapply) link

Is there any apply function ideas for efficiently running the code?

Edit: To give a good idea of code

```
`A$V1<- sample(50000)
 A$V2<- sample(50000)
output<-mapply(myfun, A$V1, A$V2)

myfun<- function(x,y)
return(length(which(x<=gh2$data_start & y>=gh2$data_end)))`
```

gh2 is a data frame with 1 billion rows.
which function itself consumes 0.30 sec for one search along this big gh2 data frame.
Intention is to find how many rows fall into this condition
Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: If your code is inefficient, just "applying" is not going to help. If you want speedup from parallelizing the problem, see `mcmapply` in the package `parallel`. This maybe useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827437/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-parallelize-mapply

Comment: Same happened. Achieved a small efficiency leverage. But not much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still haven't told us quite enough to replicate your question, but maybe my example below works. **tl;dr** I can save about 10% by substituting `sum()` for `length(which())` (I'm very surprised it wasn't more ...) and get a 5-fold speedup using `Rcpp`.

Generate example data:

```
set.seed(101)
n1 <- 1e4; n2 <- 1e3  
gh2 <- data.frame(data_start=rnorm(n1),data_end=rnorm(n1))
```

Try out both regular data frames and `tbl_df` from `dplyr` (also, `data_frame` is marginally more convenient for generating data since it allows on-the-fly transformation).

```
library("dplyr")
A <- data_frame(V1=rnorm(n2),
                V2=V1+runif(n2))
A0 <- as.data.frame(A)
```

Original function and base-R alternative using `sum()`:

```
fun1 <- function(x,y)
    return(length(which(x<=gh2$data_start & y>=gh2$data_end)))
fun2 <- function(x,y)
    return(sum(x<=gh2$data_start & y>=gh2$data_end))
```

check:

```
all.equal(with(A0, mapply(fun1, V1, V2)),
          with(A, mapply(fun2, V1, V2)))  ## TRUE
```

Now an `Rcpp` version. This could almost certainly be shortened/made slicker, but I'm not very experienced with this framework (unlikely to make a huge speed difference, though).

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction("
NumericVector fun3(NumericVector d_start, NumericVector d_end,
                     NumericVector lwr, NumericVector upr) {
   int i, j;
   int n1 = lwr.size();
   int n2 = d_start.size();

   NumericVector res(n1);

   for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
       res[i]=0;
       for (j=0; j<n2; j++) {
            if (lwr[i]<=d_start[j] && upr[i]>=d_end[j]) res[i]++;
       }
   }
   return res;
}
")
```

check:

```
f3 <- fun3(gh2$data_start,gh2$data_end, A$V1,A$V2)
f1 <- with(A0, mapply(fun1, V1, V2))
all.equal(f1,f3)  ## TRUE
```

Benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(fun1.0= with(A0, mapply(fun1, V1, V2)),
          fun2.0= with(A0, mapply(fun2, V1, V2)),  ## data.frame
          fun2  = with(A, mapply(fun2, V1, V2)),   ## dplyr-style
          fun3 = fun3(gh2$data_start,gh2$data_end, A$V1,A$V2),
          columns=c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
          replications=30
          )
##     test replications elapsed relative
## 1 fun1.0           30   7.813    5.699
## 3   fun2           30   6.834    4.985
## 2 fun2.0           30   6.841    4.990
## 4   fun3           30   1.371    1.000
```

- not much difference between `data.frame` and `tbl_df`
- `sum()` is 12% faster than `length(which())`
- Rcpp is about 5x faster than base R

This could in principle be combined with `parallel::mcmapply`:

```
mcmapply(fun3,gh2$data_start,gh2$data_end, A$V1,A$V2,
                  mc.cores=4)
```

but for the sizes in the example above the overhead is too high to make it worthwhile.