# Alternative to mapply to select sample

Tags: r, optimization, data-manipulation, sample, mapply

I created a `mapply` function to select samples from a dataset but is there any faster ways to do it by avoiding `mapply` because it is slow and I have a larger dataset? My goal is to use more matrix / vector operations and less in terms of lists.

```
#A list of a set of data to be selected
bl <- list(list(c(1, 2),c(2, 3), c(3, 4), c(4, 5), c(5, 6), c(6, 7), c(7, 8), c(8, 9)), 
           list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 3, 4), c(3, 4, 5), c(4, 5, 6), c(5, 6, 7), c(6, 7, 8)), 
           list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7), c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)))
#Number of elements to be selected
kn <- c(5, 4, 3)
#Total number of elements in each set
nb <- c(8, 6, 5)
#This output a list but preferably I would like a matrix 
bl_func <- function() mapply(function(x, y, z) {
  x[sample.int(y, z, replace = TRUE)]
}, bl, nb, kn, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by @LMc, `parallel::mcmapply` indeed is faster:

```
mc.cores=parallel::detectCores()-1
bl_func <- function() parallel::mcmapply(function(x, y, z) {
  x[sample.int(y, z, replace = TRUE)]
}, bl, nb, kn, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

bl_func.0 <- function() mapply(function(x, y, z) {
  x[sample.int(y, z, replace = TRUE)]
}, bl, nb, kn, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  para = bl_func(),
  nopara = bl_func.0(),
  times = 100
)
Unit: microseconds
   expr      min       lq  mean  median    uq   max neval
   para 11601.12 18176.46 19901 20402.4 21872 26457   100
 nopara    37.34    90.86  1275   246.5  1311  9159   100
```

I am still curious, though, of other ways to speed things up without the aid of parallel process. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827437/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-parallelize-mapply/40892117) question about parallel processing?

Comment: @LMc Thank you for the link but this function I created is just an intermediate step which I will feed to subsequent functions and replications. I'm not sure if doing parallel here can speed up the whole thing but I might do it at the replication stage. Here I was just wondering if the `bl_func` function can be optimized by using other methods than `mapply`

Comment: @LMc I gave a second thought about the parallel process and indeed it is faster than before (see edit). Thank you for the suggestion. I am still curious, though, of other ways to accelerate things.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool designed for speed and large datasets,e.g. [data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/) .

To do this you would need to reshape your data from lists to a `data.table` which is in any ways a good idea.

Here is an attempt:

```
require(data.table)

x = lapply(bl, function(x) data.table( t(data.frame(x) ) ) )
x = lapply(x, melt)
for( i in 1:length(x) ) x[[i]][, group := i]
x = rbindlist(x)
```

Now the original list of lists is structured in a `data.table` with 3 columns: the  `value` containing the actual data, the `variable` defining the vectors within each list and the `group` defining the list ID.

```
> head(x)
   variable value group
1:       V1     1     1
2:       V1     2     1
3:       V1     3     1
4:       V1     4     1
5:       V1     5     1
6:       V1     6     1
```

`data.table` has a `by` argument which means we can sample rows (`.SD` ) by one or several columns in the `data.table` like this:

```
x[,.SD[ sample(  .N, sample(nb,1) , replace = TRUE )   ],by = group ]
```

```
    group variable value
 1:     1       V2     6
 2:     1       V2     5
 3:     1       V1     6
 4:     1       V1     7
 5:     1       V1     3
```

Comment: Thank you for this `data.table` solution @MihaiV. I upvoted yours but wonder if there is some base R methods to do it without the use of any packages. I try to be less dependent on packages because eventually I would like to develop this into a standalone package.

Comment: I think you solution based on `base::mapply` is already as fast as `base` can offer.  In terms of dependencies, `data.table` has no other dependencies than R itself so a package depending on `data.table` does not bring any other extra dependencies down the road.