# Why is foreach() %do% sometimes slower than for?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm playing around with parallellization in R for the first time. As a first toy example, I tried

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()

B<-10000

myFunc<-function()
{
    for(i in 1:B) sqrt(i)
}

myFunc2<-function()
{
    foreach(i = 1:B)  %do% sqrt(i)
}

myParFunc<-function()
{
    foreach(i = 1:B) %dopar% sqrt(i)
}
```

I know that `sqrt()` executes too fast for parallellization to matter, but what I didn't expect was that `foreach() %do%` would be slower than `for()`:

```
> system.time(myFunc())
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.005 
> system.time(myFunc2())
   user  system elapsed 
  6.756   0.000   6.759 
> system.time(myParFunc())
   user  system elapsed 
  6.140   0.524   6.096
```

In most examples that I've seen, `foreach() %dopar%` is compared to `foreach() %do%` rather than `for()`. Since `foreach() %do%` was much slower than `for()` in my toy example, I'm now a bit confused. Somehow, I thought that these were equivalent ways of constructing for-loops. What is the difference? Are they ever equivalent? Is `foreach() %do%` always slower?

UPDATE: Following @Peter Fines answer, I update `myFunc` as follows:

```
 a<-rep(NA,B)
 myFunc<-function()
 {
     for(i in 1:B) a[i]<-sqrt(i)
 }
```

This makes `for()` a bit slower, but not much:

```
> system.time(myFunc())
   user  system elapsed 
  0.036   0.000   0.035 
> system.time(myFunc2())
   user  system elapsed 
  6.380   0.000   6.385
```

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007458/problems-using-foreach-parallelization and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012804/mpi-parallelization-using-snow-is-slow

Comment: Thanks @Charlie, the answers to those questions were very helpful to what I'm trying to do after I'm done with my toy example! :) I'm still not sure that I understand why `foreach` needs so much more time when using the `%do%` option though.

Comment: A big part of it is that %do% has to parcel out the pieces/assignments, send them to the processors, then rejoin everything at the end as appropriate. These steps require organizational time that the unparallelized version doesn't.

Comment: Isn't that what `%dopar%` does?

Comment: Interesting! **I got exactly the opposite result!** See [Why is R for loop 10 times slower than when using foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651664/why-is-r-for-loop-10-times-slower-than-when-using-foreach)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for` will run `sqrt` B times, presumably discarding the answer each time. `foreach`, however, returns a list containing the result of each execution of the loop body. This would contribute considerable extra overhead, regardless of whether it's running in parallel or sequential mode (`%dopar%` or `%do%`).

I based my answer by running the following code, which appears to be confirmed by the [foreach vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf), which states "foreach differs from a for loop in that its return is a list of values, whereas a for loop has no value and uses side effects to convey its result."

```
> print(for(i in 1:10) sqrt(i))
NULL

> print(foreach(i = 1:10) %do% sqrt(i))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.414214

[[3]]
... etc
```

UPDATE: I see from your updated question that the above answer isn't nearly sufficient to account for the performance difference. So I looked at the [source code](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) for `foreach` and can see that there is a LOT going on! I haven't tried to understand exactly how it works, however `do.R` and `foreach.R` show that even when `%do%` is run, large parts of the `foreach` configuration is still run, which would make sense if perhaps the `%do%` option is largely provided to allow you to test `foreach` code without having to have a parallel backend configured and loaded. It also needs to support the more advanced nesting and iteration facilities that `foreach` provides.

There are references in the code to results caching, error checking, debugging and the creation of local environment variables for the arguments of each iteration (see the function `doSEQ` in `do.R` for example). I'd imagine this is what creates the difference that you've observed. Of course, if you were running much more complicated code inside your loop (that would actually benefit from a parallelisation framework like `foreach`), this overhead would become irrelevant compared with the benefits it provides.

Comment: Right - that should explain at least part of the difference! I'm still not sure if it explains all of it though; see the update to my question!