# Why is R for loop 10 times slower than when using foreach?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

This is really blowing my mind. The basic loop takes like 8 seconds on my computer:

```
system.time({
x <- 0
for (p in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:500) {
        for (j in 1:5000) {
            x <- x + i * j
        }
    }
}
})
x
```

Whereas if I use `foreach` in non-parallel mode, it does take only 0.7 secs!!!

```
system.time({
x <- 0
foreach(p = 1:2, .combine = rbind) %do% 
    for (i in 1:500) {
        for (j in 1:5000) {
            x <- x + i * j
        }
    }
})
x
```

The result is the same, but `foreach` was somehow able to reach it much faster than basic R! Where is the inefficiency of basic R?

#### How is this possible?

In fact, I got complete opposite result compared to this one: [Why is foreach() %do% sometimes slower than for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411871/why-is-foreach-do-sometimes-slower-than-for)

Comment: This is a perfect example of how writing a package can improve upon/enhance base methods.

Comment: @Richard great, please if you understand why and what happens then post an answer.

Comment: The code gets compiled, ultimately by `make.codeBuf`

Comment: @James, yeah, that sounds like it!

Comment: So if you take your triple-for-loop, make it into a function, and use `compile::cmpfun`, will the resultant function be as fast as `foreach` ?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`foreach` when used sequentially eventually uses `compiler` to produce compiled byte code using the non-exported functions `make.codeBuf` and `cmp`. You can use `cmpfun` to compile the innerloop into bytecode to simulate this and achieve a similar speedup.

```
f.original <- function() {
x <- 0
for (p in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:500) {
        for (j in 1:5000) {
            x <- x + i * j
        }
    }
}
x
}

f.foreach <- function() {
x <- 0
foreach(p = 1:2, .combine = rbind) %do% 
    for (i in 1:500) {
        for (j in 1:5000) {
            x <- x + i * j
        }
    }
x
}

f.cmpfun <- function(x) {
f <- cmpfun(function(x) {
    for (i in 1:500) {
        for (j in 1:5000) {
            x <- x + i * j
            }
        }
        x
    })
    f(f(0))
}
```

**Results**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f.original(),f.foreach(),f.cmpfun(), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 f.original() 4033.6114 4051.5422 4061.7211 4072.6700 4079.0338     5
  f.foreach()  426.0977  429.6853  434.0246  437.0178  447.9809     5
   f.cmpfun()  418.2016  427.9036  441.7873  444.1142  444.4260     5
all.equal(f.original(),f.foreach(),f.cmpfun())
[1] TRUE
```